# Display a view in multiple views while navigating ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a view, which displays a list of data from database say for.eg. Top Categories
This list of top categories has to be displayed in all other views when I navigate between pages.

How can I achieve this in ASP.NET MVC3?

Please provide some samples or links
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

move the `top categories` to a partial page and call that partial where ever its needed

http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/